# When setting a column value to not null in sql server, do i have to set a default value for the column or should it work anyway?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If I use for example Entity Framework and try to make an insert, if the model to update has a string value or a bool, though not set, the models values cannot be null so they should handle the default value to be inserted in these fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're setting an existing column to `NOT NULL` and it was nullable before hand, then either

- all existing rows already have a value for that column (or you update your table so that this condition is met)
- or you have to provide a default value for the `NOT NULL` column so that any rows that contain a `NULL` will be filled with the default instead

You can do either of those two options - whichever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> When setting a column value to not null in sql server, do i have to
>   set a default value for the column or should it work anyway?

When you are setting the constraint as NOT NULL that means you have to specify a value to that column. It cannot remain NULL. You can certainly specify any default value to that column.

If you dont want to give the value everytime to your column then it is better to set some default value to that column else you need to provide the value to that column whenever you will make an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting column as **NOT NULL** with **ALTER** command then you have to be sure that all value of the column should not be null or you can set its default value. But In case of **CREATE** command,not compulsory to create default value since it will restrict for inserting null value with any DML command.